# Unitary irreducible representations of the Diffeomorphism group

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory

Particles can be seen as "Unitary irreducible representations of the Poincare' group" using the Casimir of the representations: $m$ and $j$. Now, is it possible to generalize this procedure in order to classify all the "Unitary irreducible representations of the Diffeomorphism group"? If it's possible, does this give a generalization of the concept of particle? In both cases the group is acting on the space-time.

Comment: Nay, one cannot construct a notion of particles in general non-stationary spacetimes. Check out "Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime, etc" by Robert Wald.